# Error al convertir el valor del parametro de String a Int16 C#

Tags: c#, .net

Me da el error al convertir el valor del parametro de String a Int16 en C# pero el parametro que le paso es un smallint, por lo que no entiendo que esta pasando
Gracias[image: Codigo]

Comment: Le estas pasando una cadena al comando, le tienes que pasar el numero que identifica al centro

Answer (score 0):

**Error:**

```
prmCentrosTrabajo.Value="IdCentro";
```

**solucion:**

```
prmCentrosTrabajo.Value=5;
```

He puesto un 5 pero será un valor dinámico obtenido de una variable entera

Para capturar el evento de cambio en el select(ASP.NET):

```
       <asp:DropDownList id="CentrosList"
            AutoPostBack="True"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="CargarVista"
            runat="server">
```

Para procesar el cambio:

```
   <script runat="server" >
  
      void CargarVista(Object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
       
        
         // DropDownList control con el valor del nuevo centro seleccionado.
         //RecargarVista(CentrosList.SelectedItem.Value);//recargamos el gridview


      }
  
   </script>
```

Comment: Con el value 5 por ejemplo si que me lo visualiza, pero claro solo me saca el Id del centro 5. Lo que quiero es que me saque todos los centros en el dropdownlist y poder seleccionarlo para visualizar en un gridview mas datos.

Comment: Pues tendrás que cambiar el comando o ver si sin enviarle parámetros te devuelve todos

Comment: Prueba a eliminar la fila  ....Add(...) donde se añade el parámetro al comando

Comment: pero depende de como este implementado el storedprocedure

Comment: Sin parametros y con una simple select si que me visualiza todos los centros. Pero luego al no tener un parametro no se como hacer la llamada al valor seleccionado en el dropdownlist para que visualize los datos que quiera en el gridview

Comment: Capturando el evento del dropdownlist y en el modificas el gridview